# Android: how to set an icon to the input type password

Tags: android, types, input, passwords, android-edittext

I have an Edit text field and set his inputType to `"textPassword"`.
The default view shows little dot icons. I would like to increase their size. I assume that there's no `"largeTextPassword"` option and you should set this up yourself.

I made a new large dot icon and would like to place it in instead of the regular one. Now I use the `setText()` method to insert the text into it. How do I combine between those values?

I'v tried to increase the `textSize` but the padding drove me crazy on different screen sizes.
I'v tried to use the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.dot, 0, 0, 0)` method but still, I'm not sure this the right way.

If someone can shed some light on this would be great.

Comment: I think increasing textSize is best and easiest solution, but what is your problem with padding?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `android:inputType="textPassword"` because this will replace the characters with the default dot character.

Add a `TextWatcher` and, as the user types, store/append the new character in/to a `String` and replace that character in the EditText with an ImageSpan of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use your advise here. I don't think i should use TextWatcher since i have a table view with buttons in it (0-9). When ever i click a number, it should store it in a string and then show the amount of numbers in the editText. I have tried to use the ImageSpan but was only able to store one image (at the left side). Can you give me some kind of example on how to place multiple images in it? i'm on a dead end here.. thank you !

Comment: I did this, but it goes to infite process and result occurs into StackOverflow error.